# awk to print lines that match and have a specific value in a field

Tags: awk

In the `awk` below I am trying to print the lines where `$10` = `reference standard` and the `$3` vales match. My actual data is several thousand `tab-delimited` lines,so both the input and output are set to be `tab-delimited`. Thank you :).

**awk**

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} $(NF-1)$NF=="referencestandard" && {A[$3];next}$3 in A in a{print}' file
awk: cmd. line:1: FNR==NR{a[$0];next} $(NF-1)$NF=="referencestandard" && {A[$3];next}$3 in A in a{print}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                        ^ syntax error
```

file

```
#tax_id GeneID  Symbol  RSG LRG RNA t   Protein p   Category
9606    4200    ME2 NG_016198.1     NM_002396.4     NP_002387.1     reference standard
9606    2122    MECOM   NG_028279.1     NM_004991.3     NP_004982.2     reference standard
9606    4204    MECP2   NG_007107.2     NM_004992.3     NP_004983.1     reference standard
9606    4204    MECP2   NG_007107.2     NM_001110792.1      NP_001104262.1      reference standard
```

desired output

```
9606    4204    MECP2   NG_007107.2     NM_004992.3     NP_004983.1     reference standard
9606    4204    MECP2   NG_007107.2     NM_001110792.1      NP_001104262.1      reference standard
```

Comment: Drop the `&&` before the `{`?  Also, the fields are numbered `$1` through `$NF`; `$0` is the whole line.  And there isn't a tab between 'reference' and 'standard' judging from the data shown.  The `FNR==NR` condition means that the file is read, saved and no more; the following terms are never executed because there isn't a second file to read.  You might be able to do it in an `END` block.  It isn't clear what you mean by 'and the `$3` values match' — they need to match what?  You need to clarify what you are trying to find.  It won't be hard to do once the requirements are fully described.

Comment: `$3` values match means that they are the same.  Each `$3` value may repeat several times but usually only have one `$10` value that is `reference standard`. I am trying to fing those in the file that do not meet that criteria... that is where the `$3` values are the same and `$10` is `reference standard`.  Thank you :).

Comment: You have to be more precise.  You mean two different rows with the same value in `$3`?  Regardless of what's in any of the other fields?  And you want both rows printed?  And if there were three rows with the same value in $3, would you want 3 rows printed or 3 pairs of rows?  In your sample data, the repeats in `$3` also repeat the values in `$1` and `$2` (and `$4`) — does that matter?

Comment: Only the repeats in `$3` that also have a `$10` value of `reference standard` are the lines to keep.  The entire line of each, hopefully there isn't too many.  The repeats in `$3` will be in different rows as well.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For just a few thousand lines, it is probably easiest to process the data file (mine was called `data`) twice — list it on the command line twice.  On the first pass, keep a record of the number of times the `$3` value occurs with the last field set to 'reference standard'.  On the second pass, print those records with the last field set to 'reference standard' and the count of occurrences of `$3` greater than `1`:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' \
    'FNR == NR && $NF == "reference standard" { a[$3]++; next }
     a[$3] > 1 && $NF == "reference standard" { print }' data data
```

For the sample data, the output I got was:

```
9606    4204    MECP2   NG_007107.2     NM_004992.3     NP_004983.1     reference standard
9606    4204    MECP2   NG_007107.2     NM_001110792.1  NP_001104262.1  reference standard
```

This technique avoids keeping an entire copy of the file in memory, and gets around some other book-keeping issues.  Since your code already had the `FNR==NR` meme, I presume you were thinking somewhat along these lines, even though you didn't repeat the file name on the command line.

If you can afford to keep the whole file in memory (or it comes from a pipe instead of a file, so you can't rescan it), you can do it with a single pass like this:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' \
    'FNR==NR  && $NF == "reference standard" {
             index = a[$3]++; line[NR] = $0; reps[$3,index] = NR; next
     }
     END {   for (i in a)
                 if (a[i] > 1)
                     for (j = 0; j < a[$3]; j++)
                         print line[reps[i,j]]
     }' data
```

This produces the same output, of course.  The downside is that you have a copy of the complete data set in memory, plus the various control arrays, so it uses much more memory than the two-pass alternative.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was think along the same lines but wasn't sure how to implement it.... thank you for the help and explanation :)